# How to print the data in an order using awk?

Tags: awk

```
ABC has x types:
x.x  used by xyzzy
x.y.z used by pqr
a.b.c.d used by mno   
PQR has x types:
x.x  used by xyzzy
x.y.z used by pqr   
XYZ has x types:
x.x  used by xyzzy
p.q.r used by pqr
```

**Criteria to get expected output** -

- Read the first column of the line where "`has x types`" is there and
  put it into a variable then move to next line and fetch first column
  of next line in another variable and continue to next line.
- If this line is just above the line which contain "`has x types`" then
  print variable first and second variable in pipe seperated format.

Expected output -

```
ABC | a.b.c.d
PQR | x.y.z
XYZ | p.q.r
```

I tried this -

```
awk '$0 ~ /has/ {p=$1}; q=$1; {print p,q}' k
ABC has x types:
ABC ABC
x.x  used by xyzzy
ABC x.x
x.y.z used by pqr
ABC x.y.z
a.b.c.d used by mno
ABC a.b.c.d
PQR has x types:
PQR PQR
x.x  used by xyzzy
PQR x.x
x.y.z used by pqr
PQR x.y.z
XYZ has x types:
XYZ XYZ
x.x  used by xyzzy
XYZ x.x
p.q.r used by pqr
XYZ p.q.r
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I actually don't understand your question at all. All answers here come with the expected output, but I am not sure the logic in those answers is the logic you intend. How do you get that `ABC` should have `a.b.c.d`? How is it related to `mno` and is such a relation important? Please lay down the rules of what you want.

Comment: @kvantour - I have updated the criteria to get the expected output, please check.

Comment: Downvoter - please suggest me to improve this Question's quality if there is any scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=' | ' '/has/{if (NR>1) print key, prev; key=$1} {prev=$1} END{ print key, prev }' file
ABC | a.b.c.d
PQR | x.y.z
XYZ | p.q.r
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
}
/has/{
  if(val && prev){
     print val,prev
     prev=val=""
  }
  val=$1
  next
}
{
  prev=$1
}
END{
  if(val && prev){
      print val,prev
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ABC | a.b.c.d
PQR | x.y.z
XYZ | p.q.r
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding a GNU `awk` solution. Tested and written in GNU `awk`. Also want to mention this may be a bit slow for huge size files, since this will read whole file as a single line.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/has/){
      if(val){
        split(val,array1," ")
        split($(i-1),array2," ")
        print array1[1],array2[1]
        val=""
      }
      val=$i
    }
  }
  delete array1
  delete array2
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A third variant in `awk` could be:

```
awk '$1~/^[A-Z]+$/ {lbl=$1}; {a[lbl]=$1}; END {for(i in a) print i,"|",a[i]}' file
```

**Explanation**

The `awk` command above has 3-rules:

- `$1~/^[A-Z]+$/ {lbl=$1}` if the first field is all uppercase, then save the file in `lbl` (for label). This is only executed when field 1 is all uppercase;
- `{a[lbl]=$1}` set the array `a[lbl]` equal to the first field (executed for all records); and
- `END {for(i in a) print i,"|",a[i]}` at the end of processing all records, loop over each element in your array `a` outputting the last stored value for the label.

Essentially, you are simply storing the first field under `a[lbl]` where `lbl` is the last all uppercase field seen. The result is `a[lbl]` holds the last first field seen under each label.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, then

```
$ awk '$1~/^[A-Z]+$/{lbl=$1}; {a[lbl]=$1}; END { for(i in a) print i,"|",a[i] }' file
ABC | a.b.c.d
PQR | x.y.z
XYZ | p.q.r
```

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` (completely indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: @EdMorton you are sooo right. Looking back over the post the `1` (one) and `'l'` (lowercase ell) and virtually identical in the font use... Yuck. Will update with `lbl`

Comment: I once spent hours in a college lab helping someone debug a syntax error and could NOT figure out what the problem was so had her start retyping the program. When she had to hit a `1` key I noticed she hit an `l` key instead. That, of course, was the problem. When I asked why she did that she said that that's what they taught her to do in typing class as it's faster to type an `l` than a `1`. Really drummed the lesson home for me about how hard it is to tell `l`s from `1`s in a program!

Answer (score 1):

Well, because you can do this with one big sed,

```
cat file | tr '\n' '@' | sed 's/@$//;s/ *used by[^@]*//g;s/@\([^@]*has x types:\)/\n\1/g;s/ *has[^\n]*@/ | /g'
```

Comment: No need for `cat` since `cat file | tr '\n' '@'` = `tr '\n' '@' < file`.

Answer (score 1):

Here another `awk` script with explanations:

#### scirpt.awk

```
BEGIN {OFS = " | "}  # assign output separator to " | "
/ has / { # on lines with "has"
    if (key) print key, val; # print the previous key | value if key exist
    key = $1;  # capture the recent key from 1st input field
}
{ # on any line 
    val = $1; # capture the recent value from 1st input field
}
END {print key, val} # output the last key | value pair
```

#### input.txt

```
ABC has x types:
x.x  used by xyzzy
x.y.z used by pqr
a.b.c.d used by mno   
PQR has x types:
x.x  used by xyzzy
x.y.z used by pqr   
XYZ has x types:
x.x  used by xyzzy
p.q.r used by pqr
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

#### output:

```
ABC | a.b.c.d
PQR | x.y.z
XYZ | p.q.r
```

Answer (score 0):

I also figure this out using array -

```
awk '/has/ {p=$1} {a[p]=$1} END {for (p in a) print p "|" a[p]}' f
XYZ|p.q.r
PQR|x.y.z
ABC|a.b.c.d
```

Comment: That would unnecessarily ready the whole file into memory and doesn't use the output separator you asked for in the expected output in your question. There's also various spurious semi-colons in it and don't use 2 different variable names (`p` in the body and then `k` in the END) for the same thing. Finally - the variable `q` is doing nothing useful, you could just do `a[p]=$1`, Once you've fixed most of the issues then you're left with [@David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58554049/1745001).

Comment: @EdMorton - thank you Sir for your suggesting this `a[p]=$1` and semicolon; but I didn't get this part `don't use 2 different variable names (p in the body and then k in the END) for the same thing` . I believe p and k are playing different role here.

Comment: `p` contains the value of the `a[]` index when you're writing to `a[]` and `k` contained  the value of the `a[]` index when you're reading from `a[]`. Both variables both contain the same thing - the key value from your input that is used as the index for `a[]`. The fact you're using one for writing `a[]` and one for reading `a[]` doesn't make them different - they still hold/represent the same thing.